# How does one determine whether use of block storage is overloaded on Google Compute?

Tags: storage, google-compute-engine

An I/O intensive server application runs on a 16 core Google Compute instance.  Index data is stored on a solid state persistent disk, and store data on standard persistent disk. Google Stack driver monitoring is enabled, with a neat dashboard of all manner of metrics. Question: how do to determine whether we're hitting instance/disk limits of I/O and IOPS? The ultimate goal is to figure out when we need to deploy larger disks, or switch to local SSD, etc. Is there a nice way to setup an alert that would tell us when we need to start worrying? What is the precise meaning of throttled disk read/write IO/IOPS?

Much appreciate your guidance.

Answer (score -1):

You can add up to six conditions per alerting policy on [Cloud Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/get-started?hl=en) and create different alerting policies to monitor the metrics you're interested in.

You also have option of creating [custom metric](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/) to make your own monitoring metrics.